# what is the load order of scripts when you start up vim?

Tags: vim

If you start up vim with something like this:

```
vim -S myscript.vim file.txt
```

What is the load order of scripts? Does myscript.vim get loaded after or before ~/.vimrc.

If you pass in vimscript commands to vim directly on the command line, when do they get executed relative to sourced and default vimscripts?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The help entry is way too long to post here, but it lists the order of everything that vim does at initialization.  See `:help initialization`.

Answer (score 41):

I believe vimrc is always first.  You can run `:scriptnames` to get a list of sourced scripts in order in which they were first sourced in your Vim instance.

Comment: For added convenience, when using [tpope/scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) you get `:Scriptnames` which loads `:scriptnames` into a quickfix list.

Comment: That is a common problem in vim of copying the output of long commands. I have a function for that:  function! Exec(cmd)
 redir @a
 exec printf('silent %s',a:cmd)
 redir END
    tabnew
 norm "ap
endfunction

Answer (score 5):

The answer is `myscript.vim` gets loaded dead last.

The vim `-V` option is a lifesaver here.  (Capital `-V`, because `-v` starts in `vi` mode.)  Just ran across it, after searching further since although the other answers answered your question, they don't show what wasn't sourced because it wasn't found.  If I could send it back in time, I'd save myself a lot of time banging my head against `strace` output.

This will not only show you all of the scriptnames that it *did* source in order, but also all of the scriptnames that it *would have sourced if they existed* in order.  So, you can discover what files you can create to load at the appropriate time.

```
$ vim -V
```

Adding it to your vim arguments easily answers the question.

```
$ vim -V -S myscript.vim file.txt
```

It shows `myscript.vim` as dead last.

It prints a ton, and winds up at a "Press ENTER or type command to continue" prompt, which lets you step through Autocommands.